# How do I rig a friction joint?

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to make a controller of some type to rotate this only up and down while the characters head is moving all around. How can I do this?
Please be elaborate, this is my first time doing something like this. I've searched and the closest thing I stumbled upon on Google was Rigid body constraints, but this just made it simulate movement on one axis and did it itself while playing in the timeline.

I need to be able to control where this masks tilt is at all times while the head it is parented to is moving in any direction.
[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: ok, maybe i misunderstood you, but if you want to control the tilt at all times, then you have to animate it manually, so set your keyframes as you like it. Then you don't need rigid body simulation. But you have to do it all manually.

Comment: @Edgel3D the animation is amazing xD

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear to me what the question is about. Is it about rigging with an armature (as one might guess from the tag and the image) or rigid body simulation (as mentioned in the text and done in Chris' answer)?

Comment: Thanks Blunder.  I'm not so sure as to what is being asked for either, apart from the mask or whatever being able to swing or rotate up and down and independently of the head's movements.    That mask looks very much like a welding helmet.  If it is why rig it?

Comment: Edgel3D, I need to be able to animate him flipping his mask up and down

Answer (score 0):

ok, i modeled here an absolutely stunning perfect face:

[image]

which is made of an UV Sphere (head) and two icospheres (eyes).

The icospheres are parented to the UVSphere so that if i rotate my UVSphere the icospheres (eyes) will move with it.

I gave the uvsphere a rigid body passive, check animated.

[image]

Then i modeled these two perfect plates like this:

[image]

The upper plate has rigid body passive, check animate.

The other one has rigid body active.

[image]

Now select the vertical plate, then shift-select the horizontal plate and
choose object-> rigid body -> connect

[image]

select the empty which was just created and choose hinge:

[image]

most important part: rotate the empty in that way:

[image]

The z axis must be on the "connecting line" of the two plates.

give your uvsphere a keyframe on frame 1 -> rotation
go to keyframe 40, rotate your uvsphere by 90 degrees
enter another keyframe -> rotation

now select your horizontal plate, shift selcet your uvsphere and press ctrl-p -> keep offset

run your simulation and enjoy

[image]

ok, maybe i misunderstood you, but if you want to control the tilt at all times, then you have to animate it manually, so set your keyframes as you like it. Then you don't need rigid body simulation. But you have to do it all manually.